# Using semaphores with shared memory while running multiple processes

Tags: c, concurrency, semaphore, shared-memory

I am learning some simple producer/consumer examples involving semaphores, but having a hard time explaining to myself why I am getting a certain result (because I am a noobie to C).

When I run two concurrent processes of the following producer, both processes get hung up and never finish:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 20

typedef struct {
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
    int nextIn;
    int nextOut;
} shared_data;

shared_data *shm, *s;

char sem_name1[] = "mutex";
char sem_name2[] = "empty_slots";
char sem_name3[] = "full_slots";

sem_t *empty_slots;
sem_t *full_slots;
sem_t *mutex;

void Put(char item)
{
    sem_wait(empty_slots);
    sem_wait(mutex);
    s->buffer[s->nextIn] = item;
    s->nextIn = (s->nextIn + 1) % BUFF_SIZE;
    sem_post(mutex);
    printf("Producing %c ... with pid = %d\n", item, getpid());
    sem_post(full_slots);
}

void Producer()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sleep(rand()%3);
        Put((char)('A'+ i % 26));
    }
}

void main()
{
    //Create and initialize the semaphores
    mutex=sem_open(sem_name1, O_CREAT,0644, 1);
    full_slots=sem_open(sem_name3, O_CREAT,0644, 0);
    empty_slots=sem_open(sem_name2, O_CREAT,0644, 10);

    //Create a key for the segment
    key_t key;
    key = 1234;

    //create the segment
    int shmid;
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(shared_data), IPC_CREAT |0666)) <0)
    {
        perror("Shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    //attach to the segment
    if ((shm = (shared_data *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0))==(shared_data *) -1)
    {
        perror("Shmat");
        exit(1);
    }

    s=shm;
    s->nextIn = 0;

    Producer();

    //detach from the segment
    shmdt((void *) shm);
}
```

The output from the first and second processes, respectively:

[image: First producer process]
[image: Second producer process]

Can someone help me understand why this happens (i.e. why do these processes never finish)?  Have I created a deadlock?  Why or why not?  I am completely stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: when using named semaphores , the first character should be '/'

Comment: You *must* always check the return of the `sem_` functions. In fact, they may fail for different reasons, look into your manual page how to capture the different cases.

Comment: in general, the usage of a semaphore is (after creation), sem_wait(semaphoreName) ..... sem_post(semaphoreName).  and when implementing a semaphore producer/consumer sequence, 1) only one semaphore is needed.  2) when a process decrements a semaphore value via sem_wait, then it needs to increment that same semaphore via sem_post,  the posted code is not properly handling the semaphores.  so when some semaphore value reaches 0 (from a sem_wait) then any further sem_wait for that same semaphore will wait forever until some other process performs a sem_post on that same semaphore

Comment: a counting semaphore, such as the code is trying to implement, will have the producer only performing sem_post.  Of course, there needs to be a consumer that only performs a sem_wait.  if the count is to be limited to some max value, then before performing the sem_post, the producer should perform a sem_getvalue to assure there is room for another item before producing another item

Comment: @user3629249  Yes, I understand that I need to use `sem_post`.  I have a consumer file associated with that, and when I run concurrent consumer processes along with these producer processes, things run just fine.  However, my question is focused to why running two producers (without executing any consumers) hang at the shown output.  Like you said, I thought it was because my `empty_slots` semaphore was initialized to `10` and was waiting indefinitely, but I increased it to `20` but still got the same result.  I think I have myself all confused!

Comment: @heez When you increased the count to `20` did each producer produce 10 items and then hang?

Comment: @JS1  Oddly enough, no.  I got the same exact output as it was with 10, unfortunately.